# Using D3 loaded with json file, How can get parent nodes value from json file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using d3 to visualize data from json file, this json file contains children and parent node. like this:

```
{
    "name": "root",
    "size": 100,
    "child": [
        {
            "name": "First1",
            "size": 70,
            "child": [
                {
                    "name": "Second1",
                    "size": 85
                },
                {
                    "name": "Second2",
                    "size": 81
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "First2",
            "size": 40,
            "child": [
                {
                    "name": "Second3",
                    "size": 50,
                    "child": [
                        {
                            "name": "Third1",
                            "size": 80
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to visualize the corresponding size value in different depth. For instance, for the 3 depth, I want get the "size value" of Third1, for the depth2, I want to get size value of Second1 Second2 Second3, for the depth1, I want to get the value of First1 and First 2. However, right now,for the depth 2,the value I got is the sum of depth 3, for instance, I want get the value of Second3 which is 50, but in fact I get 80 which is the third1's value. Also If I want to get the value of First2 which should be 40, instead I get 50+80=130. It is really confusing, I Spend two days and still get nothing. So please help me look at it, and I am really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: If you'd post your code, we might be able to figure out what is wrong. Otherwise I can only direct you to: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).

Comment: <pre>x.domain([0, d3.max(d.parent.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice(); And This:x.domain([0, d3.max(d.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();  I just want scale show the current value, not parent nor children's. IS this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the new information.

Answer (score 0):

I changed child to children, of course, and have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nivaldo/SW76w/). Is this what you want?

I have done nothing special except for the change above. The numbers coming from the different levels correspond to the tree depth, as can be seen in the corresponding text element:

```
.text(function(d) { return d.depth + ": " + d.size;});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!. is this possible to change into chart like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663     rather than tree? If I change into the chart, the result still remain unchanged..

Comment: For the chart you mention, the way the algorithm works is to compute the sum of the leaf nodes in a given branch. Note in the data used by Mike how the nodes that are parents do not have size information (look at palette under utils to follow a 3-deep hierarchy). Perhaps I am stating the obvious and you knew this all along...but doing a sanity check nevertheless.

Comment: Hi, you are right, I see your code, and edit mine, although these two are different chart, however I did it! Thank you! !!